# Amazon Prime Video incompatability with 17.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I tried to watch a movie on Amazon Prime. I got the following error message.

> Your web browser is missing a digital rights component. In your web
>   browser's address bar, type about:addons, press Enter, and then on the
>   left, click Plugins. For the Widevine Content Decryption Module,
>   select Always Activate, and then refresh the video's page and try
>   watching the video.

I looked for the plugin but it was not there.

I'm using firefox (53.0 (64-bit)) and running Ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64. I also tried Chrome browser and the error message was as follows:

> This web browser isn't compatible with Amazon Video. Please use one of
>   the following web browsers: Chrome (latest version)

Amazon seems to think it works with Linux but so far I am not having any luck. Is this a browser problem or is it Ubuntu?

Comment: You are using [Chrome (latest version)](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) and not Chromium, yes?

Answer (score 4):

The Widevine Content Decryption Module is not intuitive to install in Firefox because it does not work like other plugins.

However, it is very easy to enable.

Simply choose Preferences from the menu, then Content, then tick the box labeled Play DRM Content.  The Widevine plugin will now be listed in your add-ons!

Comment: For 17.04 this worked great. I did not have to install any extra packages like the 16.04 'answer'  mentions.  The firefox site is a little vague about this setting it sort of implys it does it on demand, but whats the check box really needed for.. Side note  I did not have to restart firefox to get amazon working, just a click the setting and  reload the page.